# How do I convert Latitude and Longitude value to a map and display it on a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, google-maps

I am working on a project, the service returns an xml that contains Latitude and Longitude 
sample xml below:

```
 <Address>60 Hyde Park Gate Kensington London SW7 5BB United Kingdom</Address> 
<Image>http://images.gta-travel.com/HH/Images/GB/LON/LON-BAG-2.jpg</Image> 
<LPrice>64861</LPrice> 
<Latitude>51.501545070000000</Latitude> 
<Longitude>-0.184810405000000</Longitude> 
<Phone>44-20-73685700</Phone> 
<Email /> 
<Fax>44-20-73685701</Fax>
```

I will like to display a map using the Latitude and Longitude provided by the service.
I am using ASP.NET C#

Comment: The posted XML is not valid.  There is no root element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
string latitude = "51.501545070000000";
string longitude = "-0.184810405000000";
string zoomlevel = "18z";

string url = "https://www.google.no/maps/@" + latitude + "," + longitude + "," + zoomlevel;

Response.Redirect(url);
```

Comment: I tried using this method, it works, but the issue i have with this is that, I created an iframe and at the back-end I did this:
 mapapi.Attributes.Add("src", "https://www.google.no/maps/@" + latitude + "," + longitude + "," + zoomlevel);

but the Iframe does not show, and the URL is a valid URL

Answer (score 1):

You need this

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Show-Google-Maps-using-Latitude-and-Longitude-in-ASPNet.aspx

I have done this just a few days back.
Let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some thing like below in your aspx

```
zoom: 50,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(
    <%= string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, 
        "{0:0.0000}", YourLatitude) %>,
    <%= string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, 
        "{0:0.0000}", YourLongitude) %>),
mapTypeId: 'terrain',
streetViewControl: true
```